# In a state machine process is there a difference if I state specifically that the state stays the same?

Tags: vhdl

In a process that controls a state machine, when the state stays the same, is there a difference if specifically stated that the state signal gets the same value as it has? In the example below, are the two lines inside the process with the notes needed?

```
--CLK and RST are input signals
type state_machine_states is
  (
  st_idle, st_1
  );
signal sm : state_machine_states ;
signal next_state : std_logic;

begin

--assume that there is some logic which deals with the next_state signal

states_proc: process (RST, CLK)
begin
  if (RST = '1')
    sm <= 'st_idle'
  elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
    case sm is
      when st_idle =>
        if (next_state = '1') then
          sm <= st_1;
        else               --Are these two lines needed, and is there
          sm <= st_idle    --any difference if they are written or not?
        end if;
      when st_1 =>
        sm <= st_idle;
    end case;
  end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fine with most modern tools.  If you omit an else in a combinatorial process then you'll infer a latch. But in a clocked process you will not.

It treats this it as an enable to drive the register.  The input is not clocked to the output when the enable is not driven.

Comment: I didn't understand, will it use a latch instead of a register if I omit the `else`?

Comment: No, you will never get a latch in a clocked process.

Answer (score 1):

when using an else statement, or generally when each code path is covered, then you avoid using latches

**Update:** when the else is omitted, you use the latch as memory

Comment: this isn't true with any modern tool set.  If you omit an else in a combinatorial process then yes, you'll infer a latch.  But in a clocked process you will not.

Comment: And when the else assigns the same value, you also use the (FF not latch) as memory. The else is unnecessary in this configuration.

Comment: This answer is not correct; please see Russell answer for correct description of process behavior.  The `else` is unnecessary in a clocked process like that in the code given with the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown along with the original question is not appropriate for FSM implementation. You are looking at **sm** and **next state** to decide what **sm** should be, which does not make sense. The following must occur in **ANY** state machine:

1) Look at the **present state** and to the **input** to decide what the **next state** should be. This must be **REGISTERED**.

2)  Look at the **present state** to decide what the **output** should be (Moore case). This should **NOT BE REGISTERED**, unless a special condition is required (for example, glitch-free output or pipelined construction - See, for example, "Finite State Machines in Hardware: Theory and Design (with VHDL and SystemVerilog)").

Comment: I don't understand why my example "machine" doesn't hold to this. You can assume that `next_sate` is determined by the inputs. And there is no output for the machine. If there was, then it indeed would be determined by the current state.

Comment: There are far more valid ways to code an FSM than the one mentioned in this answer. I also think many people would like FSM outputs always to be registered in a synchronous design, unless defined otherwise.